# A little confusion about conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

If $(X_i)$ are iid. Let $S_n=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$, then how do we compute $E(X_i\mid S_n)$. Is it independent of $i$?

I know it is a random variable. I guess that is independent of $i$, but I don't know how to show.

Comment: I am not sure it is worth writing more than it is obvious by symmetry. We do need to assume that $E(X_1)$ exists.

Comment: sure, but how do you calculate $E(X_i|S_n)$?

Comment: Hint: By the linearity of expectation, we have $E((X_1+\cdots+X_n)\mid S_n)=E(X_1\mid S_n)+\cdots +E(X_n\mid S_n)$.

Comment: I believe you're not asking the question quite correctly.  A conditional expectation needs to be conditioned on an *event*, not on a random variable (which is what a sum of random variables is).  I think what you want to ask is how to compute $E(X_i|S_n=s)$, where $s$ is a possible sum of the $X_i$'s.

Comment: @BarryCipra [Conditioning on a r.v. is perfectly valid -- $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$ is a random variable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2)

Comment: @ClementC., thank you, I stand corrected.

Comment: @BarryCipra : The conditional expectation $\operatorname{E}(X\mid S=s)$ is a function of $s$.  Call it $g(s)$.  Then $\operatorname{E}(X\mid S)$ can be defined as $g(S)$, which is a random variable determined by $S$. The conditional probability given $S$ can be treated similarly.  This makes it possible to state the law of total probability as $\operatorname{E}(\Pr(A\mid S)) = \Pr(A)$ and the law of total expectation as $\operatorname{E}(\operatorname{E}(X\mid S)) = \operatorname{E}(X)$.  There is also the law of total variance, which partitions the variance${}\,\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}\operatorname{var}(X)$ into $\operatorname{var}(\operatorname{E}(X\mid S)) + \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{var}(X\mid S))$.  The first term in this sum is the "explained" component of the variance of $X$, i.e. the part of the variance of $X$explained by the variability of $S$.  The other term is the "unexplained" component. @BarryCipra ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6):

The fact that $E(X_i\mid S_n)=E(X_j\mid S_n)$ is obvious by symmetry.

For the follow-up question about $E(X_i\mid S_n)$, note that by the linearity of (conditional) expectation we have
$$E((X_1+\cdots+X_n)\mid S_n)=E(X_1\mid S_n)+\cdots +E(X_n\mid S_n).$$
But $E((X_1+\cdots +X_n)\mid S_n)=E(S_n\mid S_n)=S_n$. It follows that $E(X_i\mid S_n)=\frac{S_n}{n}$.